# SQL DATEDIFF with WHERE or BETWEEN operator

Tags: php, mysql, date, select, where-clause

I am working on mysql query statement. I have to find day difference between two date. Date one is from my table column and date two is now(). And I need to compare output date must be in a day range like 50 to 80. I have tried with two line below code. But both are not working. Any please can help  ..

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2012-01-01', GETDATE()) AS d WHERE d>50 AND d<80

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2012-01-01', GETDATE()) AS d WHERE d BETWEEN 50 AND 80
```

Comment: mysql  or sqlserver ????   getdate() is from sqlserver  not for mysql

Comment: Would be nice what error do you get if you say "both are not working"

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I am using Caspio Cloud Database server. Normally for current date I use GetUTCDate(). That's working fine. Please consider the whole statement not about the current date. I need to know what is wrong in my current statement. Because I am not getting any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `from` clause cannot use aliases defined in the `select` clause. You need to repeat the expression, or use a subquery or cte.

If you are running SQL Server (as your code suggests):

```sql
select datediff(day, '2012-01-01', getdate()) as d 
from ...  -- you should have a "from" clause
where datediff(day, '2012-01-01', getdate()) between 50 and 80
```

In MySQL (as the tag on your question indicates):

```sql
select datediff(current_date, '2012-01-01') as d 
from ...
where datediff(current_date, '2012-01-01') between 50 and 80
```